# matplotlib lib throws an attribution error : module 'matplotlib.rcsetup' has no attribute '_validators'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I updated matplot lib version to 2.1.0 as per the requirement. After the execution of code it throws an error :

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.rcsetup' has no attribute '_validators'
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing matplotlib. I used both cmd and conda to do the installation one at a time.

Please help me out in this.
For any valuable suggestion TIA.

PFA screenshot of an error:

[image]

PS : I dont want to remove python as in whole and install libs again.

Comment: make sure all the rest of dependencies are in the correct version, as specified: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/users/installing.html

Comment: did you find solution to that problem? I have the same and couldn't solve it

Comment: Hey @Reut, Yes. Firstly, I uninstalled all the matplotlib and seaborn libraries installed through cmd and anaconda. Secondly, make sure you don't have multiple versions of python installed because you might have matplotlib installed in some other version (which is creating conflict). Finally, I installed matplotlib and seaborn again using conda. So, It is a problem of a conflict only.